# Express + mongoose + nodemon DB connection

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, nodemon

I have a starting point of my Express application

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import { connectDb } from "./config/db.js";

const app = express();
connectDb();

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;

app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Simple  server running on expresssssss");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

and the file responsible for storing the DB connection function

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const connectDb = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_STRING);
    console.log("DB connection established");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error during the DB connection", err);
  }
};

export { connectDb };
```

I also use nodemon like this in package.json

```
"server": "nodemon backend/index.js"
```

Now everytime I change some file in the project i see the console.log saying that the connection with DB was established. This means that I'm attempting to connect the DB everytime i modify one of the files. Is this something I should worry about? Is there a better way to establish a connection once and not to re-trigger it all the time? Any advices highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to worry about. Actually this is how it works. It restarts entire server when you make some changes in the code and it is perfectly fine. And if you are using node version above `18.11.0` use can use inbuilt node.js watcher using `node --watch index.js` so you no need to use nodemon. Having said that `--watch` is still an experimental feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Shooting the DB with the connection request everytime I change anything in the code seemed a bit wrong to me but I'm glad it's ok :)